# Rewrite a category

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, urls

How do I rewrite a category url that has a number at the end, to a url with no number using wordpress url rewriter? and... Why is there a number appended to all category url's?

http://www.latestnewsexplorer.com/news/gaming/pc-gaming-2/

Comment: the number is appended because you already have a taxonomy term with that same slug. slugs have to be unique across all taxonomies, because they're all stored in the same table with slug as a unique key.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe it is because you have or had another category whose slug was pc-gaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the same term for a category, page, tag as they need to be unique.

When you do, you'll get a number next to the slug

To fix them you'll need to fix the tag or page slug otherwise edit the category slug last

http://wordpresssites.net/links/how-to-edit-change-fix-duplicate-category-slugs-in-wordpress/